# UIImagePickerController crash even though correct privacy keys are set

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have the ability to pick an image from the photo library in my app for while now, but for some reason I'm now getting crashes (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`) when the user tries to pick an image as it used to.

I tried adding all the privacy entries as a test with no luck. Looking around for a fix, I noticed I'm having a similar log as those with no privacy keys set, but I have the correct entries in the info plist, the same I had for a while, I even get the permission alert when trying to open the picker. Here my info plist entries:

[image]

The stack I'm having is the following:

```
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a43d2b4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:] + 52,
3   CoreData                            0x00000001184abe90 -[NSSQLEntity _generateInverseRelationshipsAndMore] + 1104,
4   CoreData                            0x00000001185f58dc -[NSSQLModel _generateModel:error:] + 1708,
5   CoreData                            0x00000001184a5dde -[NSSQLModel initWithManagedObjectModel:configurationName:retainHashHack:brokenHashVersion:] + 366,
6   CoreData                            0x00000001184a5142 -[NSSQLCore initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:configurationName:URL:options:] + 882,
7   CoreData                            0x00000001185a20b9 __91-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]_block_invoke + 1081,
8   CoreData                            0x00000001185b12f4 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 196,
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f78305c _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f760de6 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 346,
11  CoreData                            0x000000011859e785 _perform + 213,
12  CoreData                            0x00000001184a4b87 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 567,
13  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c6a4604 +[PLManagedObjectContext _openAndMigrateStoreWithURL:options:coordinator:forceSourceModelVersion:] + 481,
14  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c6a5a3e +[PLManagedObjectContext _configurePersistentStoreCoordinator:] + 312,
15  AssetsLibraryServices               0x000000011cbfb6d9 __pl_dispatch_sync_block_invoke + 25,
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f78305c _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f760de6 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 346,
18  AssetsLibraryServices               0x000000011cbfb6ba pl_dispatch_sync + 70,
19  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c6a661c +[PLManagedObjectContext sharedPersistentStoreCoordinator] + 167,
20  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c6a221f -[PLManagedObjectContext initWithConcurrencyType:useSharedPersistentStoreCoordinator:] + 139,
21  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c6a20a4 +[PLManagedObjectContext contextForPhotoLibrary:name:] + 181,
22  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c60cd88 -[PLPhotoLibrary _loadDatabase:] + 531,
23  PhotoLibraryServices                0x000000011c60295d -[PLPhotoLibrary initWithTransientContext:name:] + 587,
24  Photos                              0x000000010b4468f3 __30-[PHPhotoLibrary photoLibrary]_block_invoke + 59,
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f78305c _dispatch_client_callout + 8,
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f7689a1 dispatch_once_f + 503,
27  Photos                              0x000000010b4468b2 -[PHPhotoLibrary photoLibrary] + 143,
28  Photos                              0x000000010b44755c -[PHPhotoLibrary registerChangeObserver:] + 189,
29  Photos                              0x000000010b4317f0 -[PHImageManager init] + 419,
30  Photos                              0x000000010b434163 -[PHCachingImageManager init] + 41,
31  PhotosUI                            0x0000000128efa305 -[PUAlbumListViewController initWithSpec:isRootSharedAlbumList:] + 137,
32  PhotosUI                            0x0000000128e91641 -[PUUIAlbumListViewController init] + 66,
33  UIKit                               0x000000010be7166c -[UIImagePickerController _createInitialController] + 712,
34  UIKit                               0x000000010be718ad -[UIImagePickerController _setupControllersForCurrentSourceType] + 45,
35  UIKit                               0x000000010be70ca5 -[UIImagePickerController viewWillAppear:] + 67,
36  UIKit                               0x000000010bc3abad -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 447,
37  UIKit                               0x000000010bc3b3c3 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 147,
38  UIKit                               0x000000010bc10f87 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 1041,
39  UIKit                               0x000000010ba9e853 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318,
40  UIKit                               0x000000010ba8b81c _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 532,
41  UIKit                               0x000000010babd560 _afterCACommitHandler + 137,
42  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4c7717 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23,
43  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4c7687 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391,
44  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4ac720 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200,
45  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4ac016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406,
46  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001115b2a24 GSEventRunModal + 62,
47  UIKit                               0x000000010ba92134 UIApplicationMain + 159,
```

The crash happens both in the simulator and device during debug and also on Testflight buids, but the funny thing is that the app that's available on the AppStore works fine.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Looks like a core data problem, perhaps as simple as an invalid index. Shouldn't have anything to do with privacy entries.

Comment: rmaddy: I'm getting nothing on the console, just the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. 
NRith: yes but seems to be from the picker, I'm not using core data ...

Comment: Might be worth deleting your derived data and rebuilding. Maybe the info.plist isn't being processed correctly. It does seem to match the `missing privacy msgs` crashes though

Comment: ok, I tried that, does not work =D .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Now its working...

I had the following `NSObject` extension I found somewhere to get the class name as a string:

```
extension NSObject {

    public class var name: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(self).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }

    public var name: String {
        return NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    }
}
```

Changing the name of the instance `var` made the photo library work again. Just in case I renamed the `class var` too, but the instance var was the issue.

Hope this helps somebody.